# Python: track job progress using tqdm

Tags: python, pandas, progress

I am using the following code to track a job progress:

```
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_pandas
tqdm.pandas(tqdm())

my_df['target'] = my_df.progress_apply(lambda x: my_fun(x), axis = 1)
```

Then the code provide progress tracking like below:

```
  0%|          | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
 20%|██        | 1/5 [00:06<00:26,  6.62s/it]
215it [00:06,  4.63s/it]                     
1062it [00:06,  3.24s/it]
1976it [00:06,  2.27s/it]
2893it [00:07,  1.59s/it]
3811it [00:07,  1.11s/it]
4720it [00:07,  1.28it/s]
5650it [00:07,  1.83it/s]
6585it [00:07,  2.62it/s]
7520it [00:07,  3.74it/s]
8444it [00:07,  5.35it/s]
9378it [00:07,  7.64it/s]
10311it [00:07, 10.90it/s]
11218it [00:07, 15.57it/s]
12111it [00:08, 22.22it/s]
13004it [00:08, 31.70it/s]
13832it [00:08, 45.20it/s]
14618it [00:08, 64.36it/s]
15404it [00:08, 91.62it/s]
16149it [00:08, 129.91it/s]
16870it [00:08, 184.16it/s]
17560it [00:08, 259.28it/s]
18315it [00:08, 365.02it/s]
19162it [00:09, 512.00it/s]
19891it [00:09, 706.09it/s]
       :
       :
```

---

I am wondering is it possible to print out info every 5 seconds instead of 10 outputs per second? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the mininterval argument:

```
tqdm.pandas(tqdm, mininterval=5)
```